# Yoga for Muscle Gain?

Tags: workout-routines, muscle-mass, yoga, muscle-gain, muscle-imbalance

So, I'm not exactly a gym-going kind of guy; I like outdoor action sports like trail running and mountain biking. However, I've come to a point where all this lower body exercise has made me sort of asymmetrical (bigger toned legs and skinny arms.)

I took a yoga class once and I liked it since there was always some new stance to focus on and things weren't very repetitive, but is that a way to solve this dilemma? Am I just going to have to bite the bullet and learn to lift or are there some alternatives for an action oriented person like me? Cross fit? Tough mudder? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's a lot of weight lifting and strength training in CrossFit. Aside from that, if you get on a good strength training program it's actually pretty enjoyable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypertrophy (muscle building) through yoga is definitely unorthodox, but with a well thought out plan and an appropriate diet, it's certainly possible (to a degree).

I recently heard a Ben Greenfield podcast on the subject. He had a dude on there touting his methods.  I haven't gotten into it myself, but here's his youtube channel... looks like he has playlists split into different body groups:

[Man flow yoga](https://m.youtube.com/user/ManFlowYoga)

Having said all that, I'd still recommend learning some basic bodyweight and load training; if anything, just to provide enhancement to your daily living. A couple sessions with a good personal trainer to go over some basics is often worth a modest investment.

Good luck!